# Will using canonical AMP make it faster even for desktop visitors?

Tags: accelerated-mobile-page, google-amp

If you convert your site or web property (app or whatever you want to call it) to go full AMP i.e. no longer keep a canonical version and a separate AMP version, is that site going to end up on Google's fast CDN as is the case when you AMP your regular website?

I know https://www.ampproject.org/ is canonical AMP but they don't address whether or not this makes it get stored in the Google CDN and being served from it when visiting from a desktop or if it is indeed being served from their host only, as is the case for when you use a separate amp for ḿobile.